# Can not post in express but can get with app.all on server

Tags: express

I set up a server using expressjs.

I use 'ALL' method to handle all request but now it can't work with POST on server    .

It works well with GET and both GET and POST are well on localhost.

```
app.all('/pull', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('pull \t' + util.inspect(Date()));
});
```

The error message is just 'Cannot POST /pull'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

I failed to restart the server and sync the code between local and server.

Answer (score 1):

```
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
res.send('POST request to homepage');
});
```

Comment: Please add some explanation as to why this should work.